# What's a simple machine to lift and drop a 100 lbs weight repeatedly using an electric motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, pulleys

Essentially I have a 100 lbs. pile driver with an eyelet for lifting it on top. (It's on rails) I want to set up and automated machine to lift and drop the driver at a variable pace. Preferably I would like to use a cheap electric motor. I can use pulleys, and/or a block and tackle system to reduce the amount of work the motor needs to do. I can route/3D print materials if need be. I have looked at mechanical systems and setups all over the internet, but have yet to find a simple effective solution for what I am trying to do.

Comment: A cam would be one possibility.

Comment: How high is the lift, how often, and for how long? Block and tackle doesn't change the amount of work; it just changes the rate at which it gets done.

Comment: Agreed. The specification is incomplete.

Comment: 100 lbm =~ 45 kgm. Wattage =~ kg x metres_vertical x 10 / time_seconds. So per metre of  head power = 450 Watts/ seconds to lift. A battery electric drill (or even a mains drill) with a "drum" driven by the chuck can be as low geared as you wish. You can also buy geared motors. || At say 120 RPM = 2 RPS (drill on low speed screw driving mode) say with a 25mm / 1: dia drum ~= 80 mm circumference = 160mm vertical/second = 6s for 1m lift so about 450/6 = 75 Watts. Say 100 Watts plus. Smaller dia drum = slower = less watts. Release could be electromagnet. Could use endless 'rope' with 'carriages'.

Answer (score 1):

100 lbm =~ 45 kgm.
Wattage =~ kg x metres_vertical x 10 / time_seconds.

So per metre of head,
power = 450 Watts / seconds_to_lift.
A battery electric drill (or even a mains drill) with a "drum" driven by the chuck can be as low geared as you wish. You can also buy geared motors.

At say 120 RPM = 2 RPS (drill on low speed screw driving mode) say with a 25mm / 1 inch  dia drum
~= 80 mm circumference = 160mm vertical/second
= 6s for 1m lift so about 450/6 = 75 Watts. Say 100 Watts plus.

Smaller dia drum = slower = less watts.

Release could be electromagnet.
Could use endless 'rope' with 'carriages' or return carriage each time.

A threaded rod driven by a drill or geared motor is also a potential low cost and 'not too hard" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your motor attached to a vertical chain rolling around 2 pulleys.

This chain with several  brackets constantly moves  a one hundred lbs metal ballast which is assembled on the shaft of your mechanical hammer and releases it on top.

It drops down repeatedly, banging you jack-hammer onto the job.